# Returning a list indicating matches in two lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a function that I need to return 't' for every correct letter in the right position in two lists.

```
def match(l1, l2):
    '''
    >>> match(['L', 'M', 'L', 'I'], ['L', 'M', 'O', 'I'])
    ['t', 't', 't']
    '''
    found = []
    for alpha in range(len(l1)):
        find = l1[alpha] == l2[alpha]
        find = 't'
        found.append(find)
    return found
```

I have this so far, but it returns:

```
match(['L', 'M', 'L', 'I'], ['L', 'M', 'O', 'I'])
Expected:
    ['t', 't', 't']
Got:
    ['t', 't', 't', 't']
```

How do I fix it so it returns the correct number of 't's?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach to do this would be using `zip` and `list comprehension` :

```
def match(l1, l2):
    return [ 't' for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x==y ]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : match(['L', 'M', 'L', 'I'], ['L', 'M', 'O', 'I'])
OUT : ['t', 't', 't']
```

---

In your code, the problem you are facing is due to the case when the *characters don't match* not being handled.

So in the `for` loop, it can be :

```
if l1[alpha] == l2[alpha]:
       find = 't'
       found.append(find)
```

where, when the characters are not same, it does not append to the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing:

```
    find = l1[alpha] == l2[alpha]
    find = 't'
```

but what if `find` is evaluated to `False` in the first line ? it still gets  overriden (which is a problem).

Can you think how to fix it by adding a condition before you're adding `'t'` to `found`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both lists are of the same size, use `enumerate()` -

```
def match(l1, l2):
    '''
    >>> match(['L', 'M', 'L', 'I'], ['L', 'M', 'O', 'I'])
    ['t', 't', 't']
    '''
    found = []
    for idx, i in enumerate(l1):
      if i == l2[idx]:
        found.append('t')
    return found
```